# Why is one of Maxwell's equations named after Ampère? Who first named it after Ampère?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, terminology

Ampère never wrote down what is confusingly called "[*Ampère*'s circuital law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re's_circuital_law)," not even the form without the displacement current term, as Ampère never dealt with the field concept.* Maxwell derived

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\mathbf{J}\qquad(1)$$

in his 1855 paper [*On Faraday's Lines of Force*](https://archive.org/stream/scientificpapers01maxw#page/n193/mode/2up), based on analogies to hydrodynamics, which he corrected to be

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)\qquad(2)$$

in his 1861 paper [*On Physical Lines of Force*](https://archive.org/stream/scientificpapers01maxw#page/450/mode/2up); he never wrote down [Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law&oldid=758353198#Equation) in either paper.

[Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law&oldid=758353198#Equation) is completely different from any of Maxwell's equations. It gives the force that current elements $I_1 d\vec {\ell }_1$ and
$I_2 d\vec {\ell }_2$ exert on one another to be:

$$d^2\vec{F_{21}^A} = - \frac{\mu _0 }{4\pi }I_1 I_2 \frac{\hat {r}_{12} }{r_{12}^2 }\left[2(d\vec {\ell }_1 \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2) - 3({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_1 })({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2 })\right] = - d^2\vec{F_{12}^A}.$$

Thus, it is appropriate that Equation (2) is one of *Maxwell*'s equations. Gauss and Faraday utilized the field concept, thus Equation (2) is the most "Maxwellian" of the four Maxwell's equations.

So, **why are Equations (1) & (2) above named after Ampère? Who first named them after Ampère?**

---

<sup>*cf. Assis, André Koch Torres; Chaib, J. P. M. C; Ampère, André-Marie (2015). *[Ampère's electrodynamics: analysis of the meaning and evolution of Ampère's force between current elements, together with a complete translation of his masterpiece: Theory of electrodynamic phenomena, uniquely deduced from experience](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf)* (PDF). Montreal: Apeiron. ISBN 978-1-987980-03-5. ch. 15 pp. 221ff.</sup>

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270767/2451

Comment: Here is an explanation given, in German though: https://lp.uni-goettingen.de/get/text/6627

Comment: @Claus Thanks, but this is wrong, as Ampère never dealt with fields: "_Ampère hatte empirisch gefunden, dass für das Magnetfeld $\oint\limits_{\partial A} \vec{B}\text{d}\vec{s}=\mu_0\cdot I = \mu_0\int\limits_A\vec{j}\text{d}\vec{A}$ gilt._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oliver Heaviside](https://www.encyclopedia.com/science/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/heaviside-oliver)'s 1893 [*Electromagnetic Theory* (vol. 1)](https://archive.org/details/electromagnetict01heavrich) mentions "Ampere's Rule [or 'formula' or 'law'] for deriving the magnetic force from the current" in a handful of places (cf. [p. 64](https://archive.org/stream/electromagnetict01heavrich#page/64)). He calls it "Ampère's 'dodge'" in his 1892 [*Electrical Papers* (vol. 1) p. 261](https://archive.org/stream/electricalpapers01heavuoft#page/260).

Probably the most curious statement by Heaviside on Ampère is in his paper "**The Mutual Action of a Pair of Rational Current-Elements**" ([***The Electrician*, Dec. 28, 1888** (written: 25 Nov. 1888), **p. 230**](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101050973542;view=1up;seq=256) = [*Electrical Papers* (vol. 2), p. 501](https://archive.org/stream/electricalpapers02heavuoft#page/500)); Heaviside ends the short paper with:

> It has been stated, on no less authority than that of the great Maxwell<sup>[[*Treatise* §528](https://archive.org/stream/electricandmag02maxwrich#page/n193)]</sup>, that Ampère's law of force between a pair of current-elements is the cardinal formula of electrodynamics. If so, should we not be always using it? Do we *ever* use it? Did Maxwell, in his treatise? Surely there is some mistake. I do not in the least mean to rob Ampère of the credit of being the father of electrodynamics; I would only transfer the name of cardinal formula to another due to him, expressing the mechanical force on an element of a conductor supporting current in any magnetic field; the vector product of current and induction. There is something real about it; it is not like his force between a pair of unclosed elements; it is fundamental; and, as everybody knows, it is in continual use, either actually or virtually (through electromotive force) both by theorists and practicians.