# Electromagnetic constants and the speed of light

Tags: electromagnetism

Was it known before Maxwell's time that the vacuum permitivity was inversely related to the permeability by a factor of $c^2$?

Answer (score 9):

The relation of the speed of light $c$ to electrodynamics was known before Maxwell.

In 1846, Weber derived his force law between point charges:<sup>1</sup>

$$F=\frac{ee'}{r^2}\left[1-\frac{1}{2c^2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{1}{c^2}r\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}\right]$$

from [Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law&oldid=758353198#Equation)<sup>2</sup> (not to be confused with one of Maxwell's equations, the [Ampère circuital law](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5059/232)) between current elements  (written in modern vector notations and with modern units):

$$d^2\vec{F_{21}^A} = - \frac{\mu _0 }{4\pi }I_1 I_2 \frac{\hat {r}_{12} }{r_{12}^2 }\left[2(d\vec {\ell }_1 \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2) - 3({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_1 })({\hat {r}_{12} \cdot d\vec {\ell }_2 })\right] = - d^2\vec{F_{12}^A}.$$

In the form Weber wrote his law, it involved a constant $a$ that is related to the speed of light $c$ by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

In 1856, Kohlrausch & Weber experimentally determined the constant.<sup>3</sup>

In 1857, Kirchoff explicitly tied this constant to the propagation of electricity in a wire:<sup>4</sup>

> The velocity of propagation of an electric wave is here equal to $\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$; it is therefore independent of the cross-section of the wire, of its conductivity, and, finally, of the electric density; […] it is thus very near the speed of light in empty space.

See [Assis](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/books.htm)'s [*Weber's Electrodynamics*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4302) and ch. 8 of Duhem's [*The Electric Theories of J. Clerk Maxwell: A Historical and Critical Study*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4976).

Also, this is a good historical overview:

- Rosenfeld, L. “[The Velocity of Light and the Evolution of Electrodynamics](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/ACQ5SN9J/Rosenfeld%20-%201956%20-%20The%20velocity%20of%20light%20and%20the%20evolution%20of%20electro.pdf).” *Il Nuovo Cimento* 4, no. 5 (September 1, 1956): 1630–69. doi:[10.1007/BF02745315](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02745315).

---

References

1. W. Weber, [*Elektrodynamische Maassbestimmungen*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4654) [[*Determinations of Electrodynamic Measure*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4310)], Leipzig, 1846: p. 142 ff. of Weber's [*Werke* vol. 3](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4654) or p. 93 (§21 or PDF p. 94) ff. of [this translation](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4310) (also [here](https://www.21stcenturysciencetech.com/Articles%202007/Weber_1846.pdf)). In 1848, Weber wrote a shorter paper, "[On the Measurement of Electro-dynamic Forces](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4861)" (also [here](http://www.sizes.com/library/classics/Weber1.pdf)); see spec. pp. 32-43 for the derivation of his law.
2. First published English translation:

   - Assis, André Koch Torres, J. P. M. C. Chaib, André-Marie Ampère. 2015. [*Ampère's electrodynamics: analysis of the meaning and evolution of Ampère's force between current elements, together with a complete translation of his masterpiece: Theory of electrodynamic phenomena, uniquely deduced from experience*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5464). (also [here](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf))
3. R. Kohlrausch and W. Weber, *Elektrodynamische Maassbestimmungen, insbesondere Zurückführung der Stromintensitäts-Messungen auf mechanische Maass*, Leipzig, 1856. [English translation: [Weber and Kohlrauch (2003)](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Weber-Kohlrausch(2003).pdf)].
4. G. Kirchhoff, [*Ueber die Bewegung der Elektricität in Drähten*](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/6TG7ABBC/Kirchhoff%20-%201857%20-%20Ueber%20die%20Bewegung%20der%20Elektricit%C3%A4t%20in%20Dr%C3%A4hten.pdf) [[On the motion of electricity in wires](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/335PCK2X/Kirchhoff%20-%201857%20-%20LIV.%20On%20the%20motion%20of%20electricity%20in%20wires.pdf)] (*Poggendorff’s Annalen*), Bd., 1857. [English translation: [Kirchhoff (1857a)](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/335PCK2X/Kirchhoff%20-%201857%20-%20LIV.%20On%20the%20motion%20of%20electricity%20in%20wires.pdf)].

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed and informative answer. It has become clear to me that Maxwell's equations are in fact a very neat and pretty way of capturing electrodynamics but they hide a lot of complex machinery that requires some level of sophistication to properly understand. I have seen a rather glib demonstration of the conserved quantities like the poynting vector in Maxwell's equations and thought I had seen the last of it. I think I shall devote quite a bit more time to truly mastering electrodynamics.

Comment: @Rascalniikov Maxwell called Ampère the "Newton of electricity" and said Ampère's force law "must always remain the cardinal formula of electro-dynamics." ([_Treatise on E&M_ vol. 2, §528](https://archive.org/stream/electricandmag02maxwrich#page/n193/mode/2up)).

Comment: @Rascalniikov Unfortunately, modern E&M textbooks (e.g., Jackson's) don't start with Ampère's force law that he ingeniously derived from 4 null-experiments, although they do discuss the related (but not equivalent) Biot-Savart Law. See also [this good intro. article on Ampère's force law](http://www.ampere.cnrs.fr/parcourspedagogique/zoom/courant/force/index-en.php).

Comment: @Rascalniikov Also, [Peter Graneau](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/997) did many experiments (beginning in circa 1980s) related to Ampère's force law (e.g., [this _Nature_ article by him](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/QPT59J3C/Graneau%20-%201982%20-%20Electromagnetic%20jet-propulsion%20in%20the%20direction%20of.pdf)).

Comment: @Rascalniikov See the article I added: Rosenfeld, L. “[The Velocity of Light and the Evolution of Electrodynamics](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/ACQ5SN9J/Rosenfeld%20-%201956%20-%20The%20velocity%20of%20light%20and%20the%20evolution%20of%20electro.pdf).” *Il Nuovo Cimento* 4, no. 5 (September 1, 1956): 1630–69. doi:[10.1007/BF02745315](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02745315).