# What were the 3 critical experiments and the argument given by Ampère which helped in determining the magnetic field made by electric current?

Tags: electromagnetism

In The Feynman Lectures on Physics volume 2, [Magnetostatics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html), section 13-4 Mr. Feynman tells us that there were "three critical experiments and a brilliant theoretical argument given by Ampère" that helped in determining the the magnetic field by a steady current. However he says he is going to skip those and come directly upon the results.

Can you please tell me what were those 3 experiments and that argument by Ampere. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ampère devised more than 3 null experiments in the 1820s, but perhaps Feynman is referring to these:

"Galvanic spirals and helices produce the same effects as magnets":
[image: "Galvanic spirals and helices produce the same effects as magnets"]

Experiment showing equivalence between helical current and bar magnet:
[image: helical current = bar magnet]

Experiment of two parallel rectilinear currents:
[image: ∥ rectilinear currents]

([images source](http://www.ampere.cnrs.fr/parcourspedagogique/zoom/courant/electrodynamique/index-en.php))

Here's the English translation of Ampère's work where he explains his experiments and derives [his force law](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6865/232):

- [Assis, André Koch Torres](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/); Chaib, J. P. M. C; Ampère, André-Marie (2015). *[Ampère's electrodynamics: analysis of the meaning and evolution of Ampère's force between current elements, together with a complete translation of his masterpiece: Theory of electrodynamic phenomena, uniquely deduced from experience](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf)* (PDF). Montreal: Apeiron. ISBN 978-1-987980-03-5.

  - Also, Ampère did not use the field concept, which is due to Faraday and which Ampère would have opposed for being *ad hoc*; cf. [*ibid.*](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf) ch. 15 pp. 221ff.

See also:

- [Ampère lays the foundations of electrodynamics (September 1820-January 1821)](http://www.ampere.cnrs.fr/parcourspedagogique/zoom/courant/electrodynamique/index-en.php) by Christine Blondel & Bertrand Wolff (tr. Andrew Butrica)

and [the other excellent articles translated into English on *Ampère et l'histoire de l'électricité*](http://www.ampere.cnrs.fr/parcourspedagogique/index-en.php).

Lastly, Feynman seems to think the Maxwell equation named after Ampère (["Ampère's" circuital law](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5059/232)) was actually due to Ampère. It was not; [it was due to Heaviside](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7609/232). [Ampère's force law](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6865/232) is something completely different.